# Drupal Taxonomy associate to content

Tags: drupal

I have some content I need to start categorizing. We've built the system a while ago, the content is growing a lot so now we're finding a few years later we should start categorizing this stuff. How can I enable taxonomy for this content?

Thanks

Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can absolutely enable taxonomy on already existing content types and nodes. There will be no effect of course until people actually edit the content to add terms.

In order to categorize the content I would recommend http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations
It's awesome and saved my in the past during migration cleanup! Throw on some "exposed filters" for node type, then add some field columns that will help you sort things, make the table columns sortable, so you can sort on the fly.

Then add in your allowed actions on the view style to enable updating taxonomy terms in bulk.
This should take care of our needs.

BTW: If you find yourself changing your mind about categories you should make use of http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_manager to MERGE terms and thus the associated content.

Answer (score 0):

You can add term reference field to your content type and this will give you a field through which you can tag your content and categories it.

Then as doublejosh mentioned you can use [Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module to categories your content in bulk as you said you have lots of content to categories.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely tough to go back and get content categorized, but you have better options that just Views Bulk Operations... unless you just have a few categories then that will do the trick.

You can use varying levels of machine learning to automatically tag content. I've had lots of success using [Open Calais](http://www.opencalais.com/) to tag 100s of 1000s of nodes coming in via [Feeds](https://drupal.org/project/feeds) in the past. This is fairly exciting once you get it going :)

- [OpenCalais module](https://drupal.org/project/opencalais)
- [Auto Categorise](https://drupal.org/project/autocategorise)
- [Auto Tagging](https://drupal.org/project/autotagging)